# tensorflow 1.15 installation numpy dependency

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, dependencies

When I check the METADATA about the requires of the Numpy version for TensorFlow(tf).

tf 1.15.0 requries 1.16.0 <= numpy < 2.0, and actually installed numpy = 1.19.2
tf 1.15.5 requries 1.16.0 <= numpy < 1.19.0, and actually installed numpy = 1.18.5

However, If I upgrade tf from 1.15.0 to 1.15.5, I need to down the numpy from 1.19.2 to 1.18.5, which is not our intention.

Is there anyone know how to avoid this big gap for numpy if I want to upgrade tf to 1.15.5?
In other words, is the requirement for numpy version strictly conflict with version 1.19 when tf version is 1.15.5?

Answer (score 0):

**TF 1.15.0** requires **"numpy<2.0,>=1.16.0"** and installs `numpy-1.19.5` while installing Tensorflow 1.15.0

**TF 1.15.5** requires **"numpy<1.19.0,>=1.16.0"** and installs `numpy-1.18.5` while installing Tensorflow 1.15.5

if you have TF 1.15.5 installed  in your system and

- you want to re-install **TF 1.15.0** after uninstalling existing TF 1.15.5 , this TF version will be compatible with existing `numpy-1.18.5` as it needs **"numpy<2.0,>=1.16.0"**

and the same way if you have TF 1.15.0 installed in your system and

- you want to re-install **TF 1.15.5** after uninstalling TF 1.15.0, this TF version will downgrade the existing `numpy-1.19.5` to `numpy-1.18.5` as **TF 1.15.5** supports **"numpy<1.19.0,>=1.16.0"**

To answer your question -

> TF 1.15.5 requires "numpy<1.19.0,>=1.16.0" and installs numpy-1.18.5
> which is suitable for both the Tensrflow versions (1.15.5 or  1.15.0).
> Also the compatible numpy version will automatically get installed when
> you install any version of Tensorflow.